# Extract path and file name from <img > tag

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I have source code of some web page, I need to find all occurrences of  tag and to extract name and location of that picture (example `<img src="../images/test.jpg" />` I need 
`path="../images/"` and `file="test.jpg"`). How can I do that with regular expressions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use lxml.html

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from lxml import html
>>> page = urlopen('http://www.amazon.co.uk/')
>>> page_source = html.parse(page)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(page_source.xpath('//img/@src'))
['http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/gno/images/orangeBlue/navPackedSprites-UK-15._V202471918_.png',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192199769_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192199769_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192199769_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-marketing/xmas10/janbargains/uk-january-bargains-loz75._V175451391_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/UK-Shoe/email/7_jan_11-amzn-sale-loz-1._V173375114_.png',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-jw/homepage/uk-wtch-police-roto._V185455265_.png',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/kindle/shasta/merch/gw/shasta-gw-bestselling-01a-470x265._V173993687_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/412wF8LJ-uL._SL135_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YC5H64AuL._SL135_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BdpTvM1FL._SL135_.jpg',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V42752373_.gif',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192199769_.gif',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51-kiOR0NwL._SL135_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51DRc-7HuxL._SL135_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51SK5htD22L._SL135_.jpg',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._V192234675_.gif',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31POT%2BzL1tL._SS120_RO10,1,201,225,243,255,255,255,15_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41hkDkhjrTL._SS120_RO10,1,201,225,243,255,255,255,15_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41zDYiAWasL._SS120_RO10,1,201,225,243,255,255,255,15_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31HqB5H8j%2BL._SS120_RO10,1,201,225,243,255,255,255,15_.jpg',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-clothing/Lingerie/UK_APP_LingerieStore_50._V171062881_.png',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-pets/graphics/B000FVC1HE_50._V198692831_.jpg',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-grocery/images/illy_50._V198779066_.gif',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-electronics/MI_Store/UK_MIN_MILaunch_50._V191178779_.png',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-lighting/graphics/NoveltyLighting_50._V192237013_.jpg',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/UK-Shoe/email/7_jan_11-amzn-sale-TCG-1._V173375108_.png',
 'http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/02/gno/images/general/navAmazonLogoFooter._V192252709_.gif']
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML for the various reasons outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You should use an [HTML parser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, you can use capturing groups

```
path=("[^"]+")
```

or lookbehind syntax

```
(?<=path=)"[^"]+"
```

There are probably a bunch of other alternatives too. Either way you should as the previous poster mentioned probably use an HTML parser for the job. Still, if you use regex, you probably need to first extract the img tags, then run one of the regex's above.